# Store A Range/Multiple Ranges in SQL Database(uppar limit can be unknown)

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to store ranges in an SQL table column.
For example ,

amount greater than 10000

amount greater than 20000

amount 20000  - 100000

amount 100001 - maxvalue

and then filter the rows with a query like ex.

1. where amount = 10010
2. where amount = 20500
3. where amount = 6235633

plz suggest how to handle with 2 columns low - high or suggest a more feasible solution
and how to store maximum unknown value

Comment: Use two columns, unknown values store as null or the maxvalue of the datatype you are using

Comment: You pretty much answered your own question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a table with nullable `low` and `high` fields.

Then you can select records like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 t1
WHERE <?> BETWEEN IFNULL(t1.low, <min_value>) AND IFNULL(t2.high, <max_value>)
```

The condition could be set without `min` and `max` values:

```
WHERE <?> BETWEEN t1.low AND t2.high AND t1.low + t2.hight IS NOT NULL
    OR <?> >= t1.low AND t1.high IS NULL
    OR <?> <= t1.high AND t1.low IS NULL
```